# Gitlist installation error

Tags: gitlist

I just install gitlist to follow my git repos and I get that page when I launch localhost/gitlist:

```
get('date', 'timezone')) { date_default_timezone_set($config->get('date', 'timezone')); } $app = require 'boot.php'; $app->run();
```

I can't solve the problem. Can someone give me a hand about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. I was able to solve it this way:

1- Be sure you have php7 correctly installed and with the apache2 module properly enabled/configured. I use ubuntu, for me it was enough with:

```
sudo apt-get -y install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

2- Be sure your gitlist folder has the right permisions for the web user. I use apache2(.4):

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data <path-to-gitlist>
```

3- Also check in your gitlist `config.ini` file that you are pointing to the folder containing the git repos, not to the git repos:

```
repositories[]= '/home/user/repositories'
```

4- Restart the apache service:

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

I hope this helps.